# Visual studio error: "Cannot seek vector iterator before begin" while implementing QuickSort with vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I was trying to implement Quicksort using vectors and iterators. But the compiler gives me an error like: "Cannot seek vector iterator before begin". I can't understand why, as the code works on Codeblocks. Can anyone help me?
There is a method to enter the size of a vector and automatically generate it with rand. In addition I have added a method to print the vector before and after the Quicksort.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void printVector(vector<int> v) {
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i < v.end(); i++)
        cout << " " << *i;
    cout << endl;
}

void printVectorIterator(vector<int>::iterator begin, vector<int>::iterator end) {
    for (auto i = begin; i < end; i++)
        cout << " " << *i;
    cout << endl;
}

vector<int>::iterator Partition(vector<int>::iterator begin, vector<int>::iterator end) {
    auto partitionIndex = begin;
    auto pivot = end;

    for (auto i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        if (*i <= *pivot) {
            iter_swap(i, partitionIndex);
            partitionIndex++;
        }
    }
    cout << "pivot" << *pivot << endl;
    iter_swap(partitionIndex, pivot);
    return partitionIndex;
}

void QuickSort(vector<int>::iterator begin, vector<int>::iterator end) {
    if (begin < end) {
        auto q = Partition(begin, end);
        QuickSort(begin, q - 1);
        QuickSort(q + 1, end);
    }
}

vector<int> random_vector() {
    int n;
    vector<int> A;
    cout << "Size of the vector: ";
    cin >> n;

    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int random_integer = 1 + rand() % 100;
        A.push_back(random_integer);
    }

    return A;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> A = random_vector();

    cout << "\nUnsorted vector: " << endl;
    printVector(A);
    QuickSort(A.begin(), A.end() - 1);
    cout << "\nSorted vector: " << endl;
    printVector(A);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _`i < end`_ should be `i != end`, also you're changing the iterator sequence with `iter_swap(partitionIndex, pivot);` and these aren't stable / congruent any longer with the situation met at the call of `Partition()`. Try using `vector<int>::iterator Partition(vector<int>::iterator& begin, vector<int>::iterator& end)` instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `iter_swap` only swaps the elements the iterators are pointing to... it doesn't change the iterators right?

Comment: What compiler are you using with what settings. And how do you run the program? It compiles fine on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nfabeM)

Comment: @JHBonarius _"it doesn't change the iterators right?"_ And that's the problem finally.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm sorry, but I don't get it. He doesn't need to modify `begin` and `end` right? The code seems to run fine. See my godbolt link.

Comment: @JHBonarius Isn't that one of the symptoms of _undefined behavior_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ please be more specific. I really don't see how the iterators are invaludated by a swap of the elements. The only thing I can think of is when `auto q = Partition(begin, end)` returns `q=begin`, then `QuickSort(begin, q - 1);` will cause the mentioned error.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, and these calls assume that `begin` and `end` should be the same as before, calling `Partition()` but that's not true.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ? No they don't assume that as far as I understand. In fact I assume that it's explicitly not assumed, as that's the whole idea of partitioning. And I also don't see how passing by reference will fix this. `begin` and `end` are never modified in `Partition`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Quicksort` function, if `Partition(begin, end)` either sets `q` to `begin` or `end` then you could get issues. So you need a check.

```
void QuickSort(vector<int>::iterator begin, vector<int>::iterator end) {
    if (begin < end) {
        auto q = Partition(begin, end);
        if (q != begin) QuickSort(begin, q - 1);
        if (q != end) QuickSort(q + 1, end);
    }
}
```